# How good or bad is it to iterate over a hash-table after checking that it contains a value you want to remove?

Tags: java, algorithm, hashtable

I'm currently practicing Algorithm design on HackerRank.

This question pertains to the challenge found here:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ransom-note

I solved this problem fairly quickly. However, I ran into an issue that kind of bugs me. I can check for a value on my hash table by using the `contains(value)` function. However, I didn't see any way to retrieve the key/keys associated with it. In order to do this I was forced to iterate through the table until I found that value again.

While I see the usefulness of Hash Tables... I don't think I am going about solving the problem in an optimal way. I feel like it's a time waster to iterate through the table if I already know it contains the value I want to remove.

One idea I had was to make two tables and have them be the "mirrored" version of one another, as in the original map is using the numbers as keys and the copy or mirrored map uses the keys as the values. However, this seems impractical and I have a feeling that I'm just missing something essential in my knowledge of Hash functions or something.

One reason I'm thinking about this is that I recently made a program that uses a sqlight table to hold data. I only need one loop to search for and delete these values, which makes it more efficient doesn't it?

Could I please get an explanation of how to better achieve what my code below does?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  int m = in .nextInt();
  int n = in .nextInt();
  String isTrue = "Yes";
  Hashtable myTable = new Hashtable();
  String magazine[] = new String[m];

  for (int magazine_i = 0; magazine_i < m; magazine_i++) {
   myTable.put(magazine_i, in .next());
  }

  Set < Integer > keySet = myTable.keySet();

  for (int ransom_i = 0; ransom_i < n; ransom_i++) {
   String temp = in .next();
   //System.out.println("Line " + ransom_i);
   if (!myTable.containsValue(temp)) {

    isTrue = "No";
    break;
   } else {
    for (int key: keySet) {
     if (myTable.get(key).equals(temp)) {
      myTable.remove(key);
      //System.out.println("Found it");
      break;
     }
    }
   }
  }
  System.out.println(isTrue);

 }
}
```

Comment: What you have designed is called a "bimap", for "bidirectional map", and I recommend checking the Guava collections for their implementation of it.

Comment: Thanks for that. Is that in your opinion the best way to solve this particular problem?

Comment: It is pretty bad, considering that `containsValue()` also iterates over all entries of a hashtable.

Comment: @MikeNakis Thanks. Is a Bidirectional table a good way to solve the problem? Could you explain either way?

Comment: Just to note, Hashtable is very obsolete, you should be using HashMap (or ConcurrentHashMap if thread safety is an issue).

Comment: What you need is a multiset, but since java's standard library doesn't have on of those, you can instead use a `HashMap<String, Int>` where the key is mapped to the count of its appearences. (There are lots of multiset implementations available, if you want to use one.) Using a Map to link the index of the word in the first list with the word itself is pointlesss. You never need to know "which word is at index 42?", and if you did need to perform tgat query, the appropriate data structure would be an Array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an easy way to do it:

```
public class DenyReturn<K,T> extends Map<K,T>{
  private Map m;
  private List<T> dontreturn;
  public DenyReturn(Map<K,T> m, List<T> dontreturn) {
    this.m = m;
    this.dontreturn = dontreturn;
  }

  public T get(Object key) {
    T val = super.get(key);
    if (dontreturn.contains(val)) return null;
    return val;
  }

  //implement all other methods of Map by invoking the inner map methods
}
```

Comment: That's so simple! Thanks very much for the help.